# Android: Socket.IO, не отзывается сервер

Tags: android, java, сокет, socket.io, rest

Здравствуйте! Осваиваю `Socket.IO` и возникла проблема которую самостоятельно решить не могу и прошу вашей помощи.

На сервере есть функция в nodeJS:

```
everyone.now.userAuth = function(callback) {

    var self = this;

    console.log('auth session - ' + this.now.session_id);
    App.UserModel.authorizePHPSession(this.now.session_id, function(user_id) {
        if (!user_id) {
            callback(false);
            return false;
        }
        App.redis.sadd(App.config.redis.prefix + 'phpsessions:' + self.now.session_id + ':sockets', self.user.clientId, function (err, socketAdded) {
            if (socketAdded) {
                App.redis.set(App.config.redis.prefix + 'sockets:' + self.user.clientId + ':user_id', user_id, function (err, userAdded) {
                    if (userAdded) {
                        var group = nowjs.getGroup('u_' + user_id);
                        group.addUser(self.user.clientId);

                        console.log('user auth: ' + user_id);
                        callback(user_id);
                    } else {
                        callback(false);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                callback(false);
            }
        });

    });
};
```

В браузере из JS к этому методу обращаются и всё окей, вызовы проходят так (просматривать вызовы снизу вверх, белые строки - это то что прислал сервер, зелены - то что послал клиент):

[image]

Т.е. после того как браузер отправил серверу session_id, он дергает now.userAuth и сервер ему возвращает

```
{"name":"rfc","args":[{"fqn":"closure__6089122486300766","args":[6]}]}
```

Теперь пытаюсь повторить те же действия только с Android. Листинг получился объемный, разместил на [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/NaYu2Qcq).

Получается что клиент соединяется с сервером, они общаются (после всех действий постоянно выводится в логи

```
I/io.socket: < 2::
I/io.socket: > 2::
```

) но вызвать на сервере метод не получается. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

UP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена: решение оказалось в типе передачи сообщения (5::: - call event), а я посылал сообщения (4::: - send message).